# How can i create an email server that recieve mails without existing user accounts?

Tags: email, server, smtp, imap, pop3

i have an email domain but i want to create an email server using that email domain but these server should be able to recieve emails and handle them without existing user accounts.

I mean, if someone send an email like "aaa@mydomain.com" or "bbb@mydomain.com" the server should be able to recieve those emails and handled them but those user accounts (aaa or bbb or other any "users") don't really exist in my email server.

I don't know if i have to program from zero an email server that should be able to do that (I use Java) or if there's email servers out there that can do what i want to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use CommuniGate Pro, Mail for names unknown in a domain can be routed to an existing account. Similar features should be available in other solutions too.

Comment: Lots of software can do this. I will vote to close, though. Feel free to come back if you have programming problems.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.